# Admob ads are not appearing in my app

Tags: android, admob

Admob ads are not appearing in my android app.. I have implemented admob code using XML method.  Though adds are not appearing but it is sending requests to admob.. ( 8 requests with 100% fill rate). What am I missing? and how to enable test mode in XML implementation of admob ads?

Here is my main xml file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@layout/back2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="30dip" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="AdMob ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:text="@string/hello"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonc1"
            android:text="@string/tutorials"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonc3"
            android:text="@string/themes"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonc2"
            android:text="@string/gadgets"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button4"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@color/buttonc4"
            android:text="@string/networking"
            android:textSize="21sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button5"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:background="@layout/button5"
            android:text="@string/win8index"
            android:textColor="#D5D5D5"
            android:textSize="21sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

Here is the manifest.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="org.core.mywindows8"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="org.core.mywindows8.Corefile"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Contenturl"
            android:label="My Windows 8" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tutorial"
            android:label="Tutorial Categories" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="General Troubleshoot" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Myfeed"
            android:label="Tutorial Categories" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MyWindows"
            android:label="My Windows 8" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Topic"
            android:label="Tutorial Categories" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ActivityNet"
            android:label="Networking and Internet" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Appear"
            android:label="Windows 8 Customization Guide" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".HD"
            android:label="Hardware and Drivers" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Index"
            android:label="Windows 8 Master Index" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Inter"
            android:label="Networking Articles" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Short"
            android:label="Shortcut and Context Menu" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".StartSc"
            android:label="Taskbar and Start Screen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Tab"
            android:label="Windows 8 Tablet" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".UA"
            android:label="Windows 8 User Account" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Update"
            android:label="Windows 8 Updates and Gadgets" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".WinTheme"
            android:label="Windows 8 Themes" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity1"
            android:label="System and Security" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Do you are getting any errors or warnings?

Comment: I would review this: https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/fundamentals as it clearly states how to get into test mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put the `xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"` with your `AdView` and remove from your `ListView`. (See below) Don't forget to clean your project.

Also, remove `xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"` from your `LinearLayout`.

You are not seeing the ad because you haven't given enough space to your Ad which is preventing display and you should see this message.

> W/Ads(363): Not enough space to show ad! Wants: <480, 75>, Has: <390, 1073741823>

To see the ad, give more space. Try something like this

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="30dip"
        android:paddingTop="30dip" >

        <com.google.ads.AdView
            xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
            android:id="@+id/adView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            ads:adSize="BANNER"
            ads:adUnitId="Your Admob ID"
            ads:loadAdOnCreate="true"
            ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="30dip" >

            <!-- Your TextView and Buttons go here -->

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

You can see this above, but to put in test mode in your emulator, use the `testDevices` XML field.

```
<com.google.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.google.ads"
    android:id="@+id/adView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="your id"
    ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR"
    ads:loadAdOnCreate="true" />
```

Do add real devices, plug your phone into your computer and run your app on your phone. You'll see your phone ID in LogCat. Is will say something in green.

You can ad your other real devices by adding them like this

```
ads:testDevices="TEST_EMULATOR, 123356r6xcfgxtysd, 456r4y6rfghghsfgd"
```

Comment: modifies my xml file.. (I have updated the code in my question). But no luck.. still facing the same problem. One thing, if I remove  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />  from manifest.xml I am getting a warning in a banner. So I think my ad placement is ok..  otherwise I would not able to see the warning within the banner.

Comment: I updated my answer. You weren't giving enough width to the Ad for it to display. Take a look at the modified XML I posted and you should see your ad now.